# Inequalities on pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, and I would like to create a new column based on an existing column and certain inequalities. For example, let

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'b':[3,6,4,2,7,7,1]})
```

so `df` looks like

```
    a   b
0   1   3
1   2   6
2   3   4
3   4   2
4   5   7
5   6   7
6   7   1
```

I would like to add a new column, `res`, that equals 0 if the corresponding value in `a` is smaller than 2, 1 if the corresponding value in `a` is at least 2 and smaller than 4, and 2 otherwise. So I would like to get

```
    a   b   res
0   1   3   0
1   2   6   1
2   3   4   1
3   4   2   2
4   5   7   2
5   6   7   2
6   7   1   2
```

So far I have been doing this by using `apply` as follows:

```
def f(x):
    if x['a']<2:
        return 0
    elif x['a']>=2 and x['a']<4:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2
df['res']=df.apply(f,axis=1)
```

but I was wondering if there is a more direct way, or some specific pandas method that can enable me to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html#pandas-cut):

```
df['res'] = pd.cut(df.a,[-np.inf,2,4,np.inf],labels=[0,1,2],right=False)
```

Output:

```
   a  b res
0  1  3   0
1  2  6   1
2  3  4   1
3  4  2   2
4  5  7   2
5  6  7   2
6  7  1   2
```

Answer (score 4):

For just a few values, you can also use `numpy.where` as a vectorized solution:

```
df['res'] = pd.np.where(df.a < 2, 0, pd.np.where((df.a >= 2) & (df.a < 4), 1, 2))
df
#   a   b   res
#0  1   3   0
#1  2   6   1
#2  3   4   1
#3  4   2   2
#4  5   7   2
#5  6   7   2
#6  7   1   2
```

Answer (score 3):

**`searchsorted`**
Should give you more performant results.  Similar to `pd.cut`, you need specify the break points.

*`pandas`*
*[`pd.Series.searchsorted`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html)*

```
df.assign(res=pd.Series([2, 4]).searchsorted(df.a, side='right'))

   a  b  res
0  1  3    0
1  2  6    1
2  3  4    1
3  4  2    2
4  5  7    2
5  6  7    2
6  7  1    2
```

---

*`numpy`*
*[`ndarray.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)*

```
df.assign(res=np.array([2, 4]).searchsorted(df.a.values, side='right'))

   a  b  res
0  1  3    0
1  2  6    1
2  3  4    1
3  4  2    2
4  5  7    2
5  6  7    2
6  7  1    2
```

---

**Timing**

```
%timeit df.assign(res=pd.Series([2, 4]).searchsorted(df.a, side='right'))
%timeit df.assign(res=np.array([2, 4]).searchsorted(df.a.values, side='right'))
%timeit df.assign(res=pd.np.where(df.a < 2, 0, pd.np.where((df.a >= 2) & (df.a < 4), 1, 2)))
%timeit df.assign(res=pd.cut(df.a, [-np.inf,2,4,np.inf], labels=[0,1,2], right=False))

1000 loops, best of 3: 443 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 337 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.06 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 530 µs per loop
```